# cognito autoConfirmUser and autoVerifyEmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

I have cognito set up with a pre sign up lambda which returns event with following set:

```
event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
```

this correctly marks user email and user itself as confirmed in aws console. But while trying to login I get the error **"User does not exist."** from cognito aws api, any ideas?

Cognito Pool is set up to use "email address" as "username" and this makes following even weirder - I can create new user with the same email address as above and authenticate fine. But what I ending up with are two confirmed users with the same email address!

My use case is relatively simple - I invite users to join via email so the email is confirmed already in a sense, that's why am using pre sign up lambda to mark user and email as confirmed/verified.

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Tomek

Comment: I am a developer from Cognito team. Auto-verifying email from lambda trigger causes this behavior when pool has setting to use email address as username. We are in process of fixing this bug.

Comment: Thanks for your response, in mean time I did switch to use 'username' as 'username' :) and above works as described.